# Symfony2 Forms old object variable gets updated after form bind

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm not sure if this is the default behaviour but I'm trying to compare the old data from an object before and after I call $form->submit($data) in a Symfony2 application.

The weird thing is that after the form bind the old variable is also updated.

Consider this code:

```
public function editAction(Person $person, Request $request)
{
        /**
         * Get the current old employment
         */
        $currentOldEmployment = $person->getCurrentEmployment();

        /*
         * Create the form
         */
        $form = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $person);

        /**
         * Submit the form
         */
        $form->submit($data);

        if($form->isValid()) {

            if($currentEmployment) {

                $oldCompany = $currentOldEmployment->getCompany();
                $newCompany = $person->getCurrentEmployment()->getCompany();

                // compare and trigger something if different
                ...

            }

            return View::create($oldCompany->getName() . " " . $newCompany->getName(), 400);

       }
```

The weird thing is that this will always output the name of the new company twice.
I even tried it with $oldPerson = clone $person but this also displays the name of the new company twice instead of once the old one and once the new one.

Comment: This is expected behavior since currentEmployment is an object.  The object itself does no change, only it's properties.  Try $currentOldEmployment = clone $person->getCurrentEmployment(); to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a feature of PHP 5.

In PHP 4, objects were passed by value just like any other variable. When you assigned an object to a variable, that variable contained a complete object, separate from the original. You could subsequently modify the original object without modifying the value of the variable.

In PHP 5, objects are passed by reference. If you're familiar with the ampersand operator, it does the same thing. Here is the [manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) on passing by reference.

What this means is that your `$currentOldEmployment` variable references the `$person` object, which you're then modifying via the Symfony form submission. To retain those old values after modifying the object, you can `clone` the object as Cerad says via `$currentOldEmployment = clone $person->getCurrentEmployment()`. This effectively creates a snapshot of the object at that moment in time. Read more in the [manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) on object cloning in PHP5.